# How to send user id details in connected app logout URL

Tags: connected-apps, logout

I have configured my external web application as connected app. It works in SF. When I logout from Salesforce, I want to send logout notification to my web application. It calls my logout URL provided in connected app, but I want to send user id as part of logout URL, so that I can identify the current user who tries to logout & clear all session details from my external application. This value is dynamic based on logged in user.

My Question is : Is it possible to append sales force user id or federated in the logout URL? Because, without current user details, my application doesnt know which user to logout (clear cached data & session details). If possible how to acheive this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you are trying to do sso with Salesforce in this manner, one would send the current [session id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_api.htm). Connected app can connect to salesforce to get the user details.

Comment: SF doesnt allow to add global variables in Logout URL. I tried with /logout?_https://myname-pc.com:7002/sso/logout?sessionid={!API.Session_ID}&serverurl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_400}_. I am getting error while saving with Error message **Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Single Logout URL: Invalid Single Logout URL**